# NativeSql not working as expected when changed to Sqlserver2008 dialect

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate, jboss7.x

I am trying to port application from jboss 4.2.3 to 7.1.1 with sqlserver 2008 as DB and I am facing issue when I changed the dialect from org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect to 2008 dialect in the persistence.xml. With the previous version dialect I was facing issues with pagination  for which changing dialect was provided as the solution. From the logs I analysed that some additional statements are added automatically.

**The version details is given below**

```
16:46:10,844 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
16:46:10,849 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
16:46:11,870 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
16:46:11,892 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
16:46:11,905 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
16:46:11,908 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
16:46:11,934 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
```

**The actual Query is**

```
select proj.proj_id,count(distinct projbid.user_id)  as numRespondents,c.customer_name,proj.campaign_id from  customer c,proj left join  projbid ON  (projbid.proj_id = proj.proj_id AND projbid.bid_status in (2, 5)) where proj.spec_id=spec.spec_id and proj.userid= :userId and proj.int_client_id=c.customer_id and proj.proj_state= :projState group by proj.proj_id, c.customer_name,proj.campaign_id  order by proj.job_id ASC
```

**The query used by JPA/Hibernate is**

```
16:47:39,206 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Hibernate: 
16:47:39,207 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)     /* dynamic native SQL query */ WITH query AS (select
16:47:39,208 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         proj.proj_id,
16:47:39,213 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         count(bid.user_id)  numrespondents,
16:47:39,214 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         c.customer_name,
16:47:39,215 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         proj.campaign_id,
16:47:39,216 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
16:47:39,217 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)     order by
16:47:39,218 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         proj.proj_id asc) as __hibernate_row_nr__ 
16:47:39,219 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)     from
16:47:39,221 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         customer c,
16:47:39,222 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         proj  
16:47:39,223 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)     left join
16:47:39,223 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         projbid 
16:47:39,224 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)             on  (projbid.proj_id = proj.proj_id 
16:47:39,225 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)             and projbid.bid_status in (2,
16:47:39,225 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         5)) 
16:47:39,226 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)     where
16:47:39,227 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         proj.spec_id=proj.spec_id 
16:47:39,227 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         and 
16:47:39,228 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         and proj.userid= ? 
16:47:39,229 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         and proj.int_client_id=c.customer_id 
16:47:39,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         and proj.proj_state= ? 
16:47:39,231 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)     group by
16:47:39,231 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         proj.proj_id,
16:47:39,234 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         job.userid,
16:47:39,236 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         c.customer_name,
16:47:39,237 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         proj.campaign_id   
*16:47:39,238 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)     group by
16:47:39,239 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         proj.proj_id,
16:47:39,243 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         count(projbid.user_id)    numrespondents,
16:47:39,244 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         c.customer_name,
16:47:39,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         proj.campaign_id )* SELECT
16:47:39,246 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         * 
16:47:39,246 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)     FROM
16:47:39,247 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         query 
16:47:39,248 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)     WHERE
16:47:39,248 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         __hibernate_row_nr__ >= ? 
16:47:39,249 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)         AND __hibernate_row_nr__ < ?


**I am getting the exception as below** 

16:47:39,262 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001
16:47:39,264 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.
```

I can see that groupby is added multiple times and the java snippet which executes is below

```
results = em.createNativeQuery(selectSql.toString()).setParameter("userId", userId).setParameter("projState", 2).setMaxResults(param.getPageSize()).setFirstResult(param.getStart()).setHint("org.hibernate.readOnly", true).getResultList();
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have two commas in the select. Is that intentional?
    select proj.proj_id,,

Comment: it was a typo and has corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in hibernate that ships with AS 7.1.1.Final.
It was fixed some time ago.
You can fix this either by

- use newer version of AS, I would recommend 7.2.0.Final (released as EAP 6.1.Alpha)
- manually upgrade hibernate to latest version in 4.2.x series (currently 4.2.6.Final)
- workaround by setting dialect to SQLServer2005, which behaves mostly same as 2008

Short term I would just change dialect to 2005 one or upgrade AS to 7.2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.I tried changing the dialect to 2005 but it didn't resolved the issue :(.  Upgrading to Jboss 7.2.0 seems to be a tricky one since approval process is there and can be considered as a last option. I noticed this issue got resolved sometimes if we used positional parameters since it is the correct one. For the moment I got over the problem by using Views.

Comment: Just to update the status of this issue, option of upgrading AS to 7.2 works as I deployed it and tested. The problem is not appearing. Will check with the customer since the first line in the welcome page of Jboss ("This is early access software and is not intended for production use") makes tougher to get approval :(. Also,  I saw discussion in forum saying it could be used for production.